# SQL Getting a greater value of a datetime value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table such as:

```
field a (datetime)
2015-06-24 10:15:11.2130000
2015-06-24 10:15:22.0330000
```

If I use the following query I get the proper result:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1 AS T WHERE T.a > '2015-06-24 10:15:11.2130000'
```

However If i ignore the last part of the value,it returns me both records:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1 AS T WHERE T.a > '2015-06-24 10:15:11'
```

What gives?

Comment: `'2015-06-24 10:15:11'` is treated as `'2015-06-24 10:15:11:000'` so both rows are returned.

Comment: Great link: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Time](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, what did you expect? `2015-06-24 10:15:11` is the same as `2015-06-24 10:15:11:000000`, so both

```
2015-06-24 10:15:11.2130000
2015-06-24 10:15:22.0330000
```

are greater than that.

But there's only one record with a timestamp greater than `2015-06-24 10:15:11.2130000`

Comment: Glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 1):

It gives you both rows because both:

```
2015-06-24 10:15:11.2130000
2015-06-24 10:15:22.0330000
```

are greater then:

```
2015-06-24 10:15:11.0000000
```